# callout pops up behind the pins in MKMapView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I have 10 custom annotations on my map but sometimes the callout pops out behind the pins.. any idea to resolve this?

I have checked out this link 
[Z-ordering of MKAnnotationViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681565/z-ordering-of-mkannotationviews/1848874#1848874)

but since my callouts are not popping up by tap but they are popping up by click on button so this answer is worthless to me.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: if you are not clear with the question.. feel free to comment.

Comment: i don't know if it works, but just to know, have you tried to call bringSubviewToFront on the view of the selected annotation?

Comment: in mapview didnt find any such method.. it crashes if i pass annotation as subview :(

Comment: I have tried to bringSubviewToFront with annotationview...[self.mapview bringSubviewToFron: annotationView] but still its the same :(

Comment: Is the callout view custom or the annotation view?  Have you implemented viewForAnnotation and are you using MKPinAnnotationView?

Comment: @suresh varma bringSubViewTo front is a method of UIView, so you should call like [mapView bringSubViewToFront:annotation.view];...Ok i see now your last comment :)

Comment: @mat dats what i have written in the previous comment..

Comment: @anna Kerenina.. I am not using MKPinAnnotationView. The callout view is annotattionview nut its custom. I have used all the functions required in MKMapvview. including viewForAnnotation

Comment: Just checking. Are you using [mapView selectAnnotation:animated:] to pop up callouts???

Comment: no.. it was not working for me.... so i used -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)aView

Comment: Can you post the code in viewForAnnotation and didSelectAnnotationView?

Comment: mapView:didSelectAnnotationView: is where you would create a "custom callout", but not to trigger the callout.  Used in that way could cause your Z-Order problem because a view would get drawn but none of the setup would have been completed by mapView.  I'd investigate why selectAnnotation:animated: isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is because some where in your code you are calling bringSubviewToFront on the annotationView.

Comment: Yes i an adding a transparent view on the top of the map which lightens the map when my  custom annotations are there on map. so to make my annotations clickable I have to call them by bringsubviewtofront. but i have done the same for callout also but it dont comes out :(

Comment: Suresh, try calling the bringSubviewToFron on the map superView instead of the mapview. 

self.mapview.superView bringSubviewToFront: annotationView